# this week Thursday relative dates PHP

Tags: php, date, datetime

I can get this week Thursday by doing below

```
$startdate = (new DateTime())->setTime(0,0,0);
$startdate->setISODate($startdate->format("Y"), $startdate->format("W"), 4);
```

But if i try a relative date it get this week Thursday before or on Thursday and gets next Thursday after Thursday.

```
$startdate = (new DateTime('thursday'))->setTime(0,0,0);
```

I also tried "this thursday" relative date but it doesnt return what i would excpect, it acts like "thursday". I can use the setISODate but im am just curious if i can do with a relative date since it would be easier.

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$startdate1 = (new DateTime('thursday last week'))->setTime(0,0,0); //2017-01-19
$startdate2 = (new DateTime('thursday this week'))->setTime(0,0,0); //2017-01-26
$startdate3 = (new DateTime('thursday next week'))->setTime(0,0,0); //2017-02-02
```